# BitCoin Gateway Proccessing Time

Tags: php, bitcoin, gateway, event-receiver

I want to write a bitcoin gateway using BlockChain API.

With this link we get an address for receiving bitcoin:

```
https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&address=169b4EpdsPNPXgXNsrU9g56XXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=http%3A%2f%2fhost.com%2fbc%2frec.php%3Fsecret%3D234r
```

Here `169b4EpdsPNPXgXNsrU9g56XXXXXXXXXXXX` is my bitcoin addres. We will give this response:

```
{"callback_url":"http:\/\/host.com\/bc\/rec.php?secret=234r","input_address":"199r12qVmuy7EUSavtpzSGTx1rp15dd6e","destination":"169b4EpdsPNPXgXNsrU9g56XXXXXXXXXXXX","fee_percent":0}
```

and our customer should send bitcoins to `199r12qVmuy7EUSavtpzSGTx1rp15dd6e` (the input address).

but after sending bitcoin to this address, our main address (`169b4EpdsPNPXgXNsrU9g56XXXXXXXXXXXX`) won't receive any bitcoins.

Comment: Is the transaction in a block and waiting to be confirmed?

Comment: the problem was that BlockChain accept at minimum 0.005 bitcoin per transaction.